# How to have Send To comprise of emails from worksheets that were proven true

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, email, outlook

I am trying to get my email lists from all worksheets that apply to the set rules to pull the email lists from said worksheet when appropriate. The column for mailing is S for every worksheet. I'm new to vba so I'm struggling a bit. This is the code I currently have. I guess I want the rules to kind of apply to the email list as well and pull from pages that have been proven true to generate the email in the first place. Thank you in advance for any help.

```
Option Explicit
Sub Main_AllWorksheets()
  Dim sh As Worksheet, i As Long, shtsRotations As String
  Dim shtsFunctions As String, shtsOK As String
  Dim shtsManufacture As String



For Each sh In ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets
    If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("O3:O70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsRotations = shtsRotations & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Rotations)"
    End If

    If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("P3:P70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsFunctions = shtsFunctions & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Functions)"
    End If
    

    
     If Application.CountIf(sh.Range("Q3:Q70"), "<1") > 0 Then
        shtsManufacture = shtsManufacture & vbLf & sh.Name
    Else
        shtsOK = shtsOK & vbLf & sh.Name & " (Manufacturing Date)"
    End If

Next sh
 Dim myDataRng As Range


Set myDataRng = Range("S2:S15" & Cells(Rows.Count, "S").End(xlUp).Row)

Dim cell As Range
Dim iCnt As Integer
Dim sMail_ids As String


For Each cell In myDataRng
    If Trim(sMail_ids) = "" Then
        sMail_ids = cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    Else
        sMail_ids = sMail_ids & vbCrLf & ";" & cell.Offset(1, 0).Value
    End If
Next cell

Set myDataRng = Nothing         ' Clear the range.


If Len(shtsRotations) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail sMail_ids, "Equipment rotations are due!", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsRotations & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment needs to be rotated by the red dates, indicating their last rotation."

End If



If Len(shtsFunctions) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail "sMail_ids", "Equipment functions are due! ", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsFunctions & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment needs to be functioned by the red dates, indicating their last function."
End If

If Len(shtsManufacture) > 0 Then
    SendReminderMail "test@test.com", "Manufacturing date has surpassed 3 years!", _
           "Hello Team, " & vbNewLine & vbNewLine & _
           "Check customer sheets: " & shtsRotations & vbLf & vbNewLine & _
           "In the attatched workbook, you can see what equipment has reached it's 3 years past manufacturing."
End If


If Len(shtsOK) > 0 Then
    MsgBox "These sheets are OK: " & vbLf & shtsOK, vbInformation
End If

 End Sub


Sub SendReminderMail(sTo As String, sSubject As String, sBody As String)

 Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim TempFilePath As String
Dim TempFileName As String
Dim FileExtStr As String
Dim OutApp As Object
Dim OutMail As Object

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook


TempFilePath = Environ$("temp") & "\"
TempFileName = "Copy of " & wb1.Name & " " & Format(Now, "dd-mmm-yy h-mm-ss")
FileExtStr = "." & LCase(Right(wb1.Name, Len(wb1.Name) - InStrRev(wb1.Name, ".", , 1)))

wb1.SaveCopyAs TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr
Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr)

wb2.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Value = "Copy created on " & Format(Date, "dd-mmm-yyyy")

wb2.Save


Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)


On Error Resume Next
With OutMail
    .to = sTo
    .CC = ""
    .BCC = ""
    .Subject = sSubject
    .Body = sBody
    .Attachments.Add wb2.FullName

    .Display   'or use .Display
End With
On Error GoTo 0
wb2.Close savechanges:=False

Kill TempFilePath & TempFileName & FileExtStr

Set OutMail = Nothing
Set OutApp = Nothing

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With
 MsgBox "Your Automated Email for the Workbook was successfully ran at " & TimeValue(Now), vbInformation


End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Recipients` property of the `MailItem` class for specifying recipients. For example:

```
        recipients = mail.Recipients
        ' now we add new recipietns to the e-mail
        recipientTo = recipients.Add("Eugene Astafiev")
        recipientTo.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olTo
        recipientCC = recipients.Add("Dmitry K.")
        recipientCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olCC
        recipientBCC = recipients.Add("eugene.astafiev@somedomain.com")
        recipientBCC.Type = Outlook.OlMailRecipientType.olBCC
        retValue = recipients.ResolveAll()
```

Read more about that in the following articles:

- [How To: Fill TO,CC and BCC fields in Outlook programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/08/outlook-fill-recipients-programmatically/)
- [How To: Create and send an Outlook message programmatically](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/02/outlook-create-send-message/)